# Can a weakly reachable Object be retrieved through WeakReference

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, weak-references

I know what `WeakReference` is and I read its documentation and many blogs and SO threads. However, it is still unclear to me whether the following flow can actually happen.

1. object `X` being referenced with strong reference `strRef` and weak reference `weakRef`
2. `strRef` is being cleared on a random thread
3. `weakRef` is being dereferenced on a random thread
4. the reference retrieved in the previous step is assigned to `strRef`

There are many discussions about how weak references are being cleared upon GC, but, to the best of my knowledge, GC does not happen after each reference clearance. Therefore, it looks like a weakly reachable object could potentially be "resurrected" by the step #3 above if GC did not happen between steps #2-#3.

Such a race condition is very inconvenient and even dangerous, therefore I think that there should be something that prevents it, but I want to be completely sure here.

So, is there a specification that ensures that weakly referenced objects can't be resurrected, and are there any caveats related to multithreading?

Comment: Yes. Deferencing a `WeakReference` or `SoftReference` **will** prevent GC of the referenced `Object` until such time as there are once again no strong references. This is in fact the very reason that `PhamtomReference` cannot be deferenced. This is not a "_race condition_" and it is not "_dangerous_". It is only "_inconvinient_" if you don't understand how this works - it is the way it **must** work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I see it as a race condition and dangerous only in context of my current dealing with pub-sub with weak subscribers, not in general. This might lead to subscribers (seemingly) randomly receiving spurious notifications even after all strong references to them were cleared. Anyway, thanks for you input. Do you happen to have any links to the relevant parts of documentation or blog articles?

Comment: I don't understand, why are you relying on reachability to determine liveness? You can see that in any framework build around pub/sub then the actors should be shut down explicitly when they're done - this prevents all sorts of weird behaviour.

Comment: I'm building a complex and deep hierarchy of UI related classes (in Android). I thought I could rely on weak references in order to subscribe these UI classes to an event bus, such that there will be no need to unsubscribe them later. Probably not a good idea after all.

Comment: Exactly, and in each level of the hierachy the parent tells its children whether they are currently visible. It will also tell its children if its being removed or added to a parent itself. This simple DAG allows all these problems to largely be fixed - it also allows for cycle detection and other such niceities.

Comment: Weak subscription is never a good idea. Having receivers not being removed, is only one possible issue. Usually, you don't register a reference to the component, but a listener or similar kind of binding object. And if that object is only weakly referenced, it can get garbage collected, even if the target component is still reachable. So you would need an additional reference from the target to the listener to keep it alive, which complicates the code instead of making it simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore, it looks like a weakly reachable object could potentially be "resurrected" by the step #3 above if GC did not happen between steps #2-#3.

Correct, even if a GC it has run, not all weak references have to be cleared e.g. when a minor collection is run an object in tenured space is not cleaned up. Only a Full GC can ensure all weak references are cleared.

> Such a race condition is very inconvenient and even dangerous, therefore I think that there should be something that prevents it,

It's something you must check for at any point given you have no idea when the background thread clears the strong reference. NOTE: clearing a strong reference just means setting a memory value to `null` nothing more.

> is there a specification that ensures that weakly referenced objects can't be resurrected, and are there any caveats related to multithreading?

Even discarded object can be resurrected by setting a reference to `this` in the `finalise` method.  I would recommend you not rely on this behaviour. References setting are not a source of messaging nor an operation which has much thread safety guarantees.

> I thought I could rely on weak references in order to subscribe these UI classes to an event bus, such that there will be no need to unsubscribe them later.

You can but you have to check whether the listener is still active. Just because you could get a weak reference to it doesn't mean you didn't intend to discard it.